# Haskell theorem proving tactics as indexed functors and monads

Tags: haskell, monads, theorem-proving

I am trying to follow along with [this blog post](https://ivanbakel.github.io/posts/theorem-proving-in-haskell/) to make a simple intuitionistic theorem proving language in Haskell. Mr. van Bakel suggests using indexed monads for proof state manipulation; here are the building pieces to an indexed monad (equivalent to the definitions from `Control.Monad.Indexed`):

```hs
class IFunctor f where
  imap :: (a -> b) -> f j k a -> f j k b

class IFunctor m => IPointed m where
  ipure :: a -> m i i a

class IPointed m => IApplicative m where
  iap :: m i j (a -> b) -> m j k a -> m i k b

class IApplicative m => IMonad m where
  ibind :: (a -> m j k b) -> m i j a -> m i k b

ijoin :: IMonad m => m i j (m j k a) -> m i k a
ijoin = ibind id

infixr 1 =<<<
infixl 1 >>>=

(>>>=) :: IMonad m => m i j a -> (a -> m j k b) -> m i k b
m >>>= k = ibind k m

(=<<<) :: IMonad m => (a -> m j k b) -> m i j a -> m i k b
(=<<<) = ibind
```

I am struggling to properly instantiate these classes with the following definition of `Tactic`:

```hs
data Tactic i j a = Tactic ((a -> j) -> i)
```

Starting with `IFunctor`:

```hs
instance IFunctor Tactic where
  imap f (Tactic g) = Tactic (\ h -> g (h . f))

-- f :: a -> b
-- g :: (a -> j) -> i
-- h :: b -> j
```

And now to make it pointed:

```hs
instance IPointed Tactic where
  ipure a = Tactic (\ h -> h a)
```

Simple enough. I cannot wrap my head around constructing the applicative and monadic instances, however. My guess for the monad is

```hs
instance IMonad Tactic where
  ibind f (Tactic g) = Tactic (\ h -> imap g (imap h . f))

-- f :: a -> Tactic ((b -> k) -> j)
-- g :: (a -> j) -> i
-- h :: b -> k
-- RHS :: Tactic ((b -> k) -> i)
```

since the signatures seem to check out. I am completely stumped by the applicative instance though.

```hs
instance IApplicative Tactic where
  iap (Tactic f) (Tactic g) = Tactic (\ h -> ???)

-- f :: ((a -> b) -> j) -> i
-- g :: (a -> k) -> j
-- h :: b -> k
-- RHS :: Tactic ((b -> k) -> i)
```

What would you suggest?

---

Edit: I got the applicative instance to work via

```hs
instance IApplicative Tactic where
  iap (Tactic f) (Tactic g) = Tactic (\ h -> f (\ x -> g (h . x)))

-- f :: ((a -> b) -> j) -> i
-- g :: (a -> k) -> j
-- h :: b -> k
-- RHS :: Tactic ((b -> k) -> i)
-- x :: a -> b, h . x :: a -> k
```

thanks to Li-Yao's hint on the typo in `g` signature, but I am still stuck on the bind definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

- There's a typo in the type of `g` in the comment (EDIT: now fixed)
- What's the type of the hole `???`? (see more details below)
- Another way is to implement `iap` using `imap` and `ibind`, the same way you can implement `(<*>)` using `fmap` and `(>>=)`
- `Tactic` is a more indexed version of the continuation monad `type Cont r a = (a -> r) -> r`, so if you're familiar with that, the implementation is the same.

---

You can do **type-driven programming** by putting a hole `_` and by looking at the error message from the compiler.

```
instance IMonad Tactic where
  ibind f (Tactic g) = Tactic _

-- error: Found hole: _ :: (b -> k) -> i
```

When the hole has a function type, it's always safe to start with a lambda:

```
instance IMonad Tactic where
  ibind f (Tactic g) = Tactic (\h -> _)

-- error: Found hole: _ :: i
-- Relevant bindings include
--        h :: b -> k
--        g :: (a -> j) -> i
--        f :: a -> Tactic j k b
```

The only way to produce an `i` is to apply `g` to some argument.

```
instance IMonad Tactic where
  ibind f (Tactic g) = Tactic (\h -> g _)

-- error: Found hole: _ :: a -> j
```

Again a function.

```
instance IMonad Tactic where
  ibind f (Tactic g) = Tactic (\h -> g (\a -> _))

-- error: Found hole: _ :: j
-- Relevant bindings include
--        a :: a
--        h :: b -> k
--        g :: (a -> j) -> i
--        f :: a -> Tactic j k b
```

There is no obvious way to produce a `j`, but there is a way to use the `a` which we just introduced, with `f :: a -> Tactic j k b` (and upon closer inspection we see that it will in fact yield a `j` eventually). We can then pattern-match on the resulting `Tactic` to get some more data:

```
instance IMonad Tactic where
  ibind f (Tactic g) = Tactic (\h -> g (\a ->
    let Tactic p = f a in _))

-- error: Found hole: _ :: j
-- Relevant bindings include
--        p :: (b -> k) -> j
--        a :: a
--        h :: b -> k
--        g :: (a -> j) -> i
--        f :: a -> Tactic j k b
```

The final step is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I fixed the typo and added a signature for the RHS of the `iap` definition, though I don't get what you mean by implementing `iap` with `ibind`. You'd need to construct the applicative instance to have bind in the first place, right?

Comment: The `Applicative` instance must exist for the `Monad` instance to exist, but there is no constraint on how their definitions depend on each other.

Comment: @AndriiKozytskyi I added some details on programming with typed holes.

Comment: Splendid. I was not aware of this functionality of the compiler, got the monad to work now.