# Defining a function that satisfies a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, ghci

Considering the type

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
```

I want to create a function that satisfies this type...

I know `foo x y = y (\z -> x)` satisfies this type as confirmed with `:type` in GHCi, but how would I get to this final function manually, or step by step?

I also know `foo2 f g = \x -> f (g x)` would also satisfy `foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b` but don't also know how to get to this function.

Comment: Try hole-driven programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71621972/haskell-theorem-proving-tactics-as-indexed-functors-and-monads/71622195#71622195

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of fitting the matching pieces of a puzzle together. The same-named pieces *match*. The type of `foo` means it's a function with two parameters:

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
--     a    f

foo a f     =     c
 -- a       :: a
 --   f g   ::    c
 --     g b :: a
  where
  c = f g         -- produce a c-type value
  g       b =  a  -- define g to produce
                  --   the value a
```

*`f`* we're given, but *`g`* we must invent so that it returns `a`; fortunately, we're already given an `a`:

```
-- f :: ((b -> a) -> c)
--       g

-- g ::   b -> a
```

`a` is given to us as a parameter of `foo`, and `b` is just an unused parameter of `g`.

Next we can substitute and simplify, using the fact that writing this:

```
p :: q -> r
p    q =  r...
```

is the same as writing this:

```
p :: q -> r
p = \q -> r...
```

where we use `r...` to indicate an expression whose type is `r`.

Also, `s -> t -> r` is the same as `s -> (t -> r)` because, similarly,

```
h :: s ->   t -> r
h    s      t =  r...
h    s =  (\t -> r...)
h = \s -> (\t -> r...)
```

all express the same thing.

Your second question can be addressed in the same manner.

`x :: a` means "the value `x` has type `a`"; `a :: a` means "the value `a` has type `a`". The same name `a` can be used in two different roles; when you're accustomed to it, it can actually  be quite a helpful mnemonic.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71761873/849891).

Comment: Still don't quite fully understand the first piece matching area? Can I ask for more clarification please?

Comment: yes of course.  `x :: a` means "a value `x` has type `a`"; `a :: a` means "a value `a` has type `a`". the same `a` can be used in two different roles; when you're accustomed to it, it actually can be a helpful mnemonic. what else exactly is unclear?

Comment: I think the OP may be wondering how you figured out the first four lines of the first code block.  It may help to simply talk through the process... "`foo` is a function of two args, and we've named them `a` and `f`.  This `f` has type `(b -> a) -> c` which means it's a function that takes one arg, etc., etc."

Comment: Ah yes, I was wondering more closely how the first four lines of the first code block were deducted ^.^

Comment: Also, does this method give a one line function? I'm confused on if the where clauses turn into a one-line function...

Comment: Yes, as the answer says, you can substitute and simplify following the rule as shown there, and you'll get a one-liner.

Comment: you can find more more verbal explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338264/849891).

Answer (score 0):

An underscore `_`, or an undefined name beginning with an underscore such as `_what`, is treated by GHC as a “hole” that you want to fill in. You can use this to ask what type the compiler is expecting, and this can be helpful in figuring out how to iteratively fill in the program. Thankfully, this is a case where it’s *very* helpful, so I can easily go through it step by step in GHCi (with `>` indicating the prompt). We begin with a hole `foo = _`:

```
> foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c; foo = _
```

And we receive a message saying `Found hole: _ :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c`. GHC suggests `foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c` as a valid way of filling in the hole, and indeed `foo = foo` is legal, it’s just not the answer we’re looking for, since it represents an infinite loop.

Instead, we can look at the type and break it down into parts from the top down. We begin with a function type (`->`) whose input is `a` and whose output is `((b -> a) -> c) -> c`. We can make a function value using a lambda expression, inventing a name for the `a` value, say `x`, and put another hole for the body:

```
> foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c; foo = \ x -> _

…
    • Found hole: _ :: ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
…
```

It now mentions that we have `x :: a` available to work with, in addition to `foo`, but this isn’t quite enough, so next we can take apart `((b -> a) -> c) -> c` into its input `((b -> a) -> c)` and output `c`. (From now on, for brevity’s sake, I’ll also skip repeating the type signature of `foo`.)

```
> foo :: …; foo = \ x -> \ f -> _

…
    • Found hole: _ :: c
…
```

We can’t take apart the type variable `c` any further, and we know we need to make a value of type `c`, so we can look at what we have available:

- `f :: (b -> a) -> c`
- `x :: a`
- `foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c`

So our options are:

1. Recursively call `foo`
2. Call `f`

#1 would quickly put us back in the same situation we’re in, so #2 is all that’s left. `f` expects a value of type `b -> a` as an argument:

```
> foo :: …; foo = \ x -> \ f -> f _

…
    • Found hole: _ :: b -> a
…
```

So again we can write a lambda:

```
> foo :: …; foo = \ x -> \ f -> f (\ y -> _)

…
    • Found hole: _ :: a
…
```

The only way we can produce a value of the unknown type `a` is to use the value `x :: a` that we’ve been given, so the final result is this:

```
foo = \ x -> \ f -> f (\ y -> x)
```

And that can be written in exactly the same form as you put in your question, using a little syntactic sugar, and a couple different choices of variable names:

```
foo     = \ x -> \ f -> f (\ y -> x)
foo x   =        \ f -> f (\ y -> x)
foo x f =               f (\ y -> x)

foo x y =               y (\ z -> x)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
```

says that foo has to take an `a` and a function with type `(b -> a) -> c` and somehow produce a c.

```
foo a function = c
```

where `a::a` and `function::(b -> a) -> c`
but where can we get the c from?

Good news: `function` makes `c`s for us.

Let's use that. `function::(b->a) -> c` so we can get a `c` if we give it a `(b->a)`.

So we need to first make a helper function that takes `b`s and gives us `a`s:

```
foo a function = 
   let helper b = a
```

That's fine! I already had an `a` so I could use that. We just need to hand `function` the `helper` we just made:

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
foo a function = 
   let helper b = a 
   in function helper
```

Now notice that `helper` ignores its input, so we could write

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
foo a function = 
   let helper _ = a 
   in function helper
```

And we can use lambda notation for helper:

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
foo a function = 
   let helper = \_ -> a 
   in function helper
```

But now we could just write `(\_ -> a)` instead of helper:

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
foo a function = 
   function (\_ -> a)
```

And finally, lets abbreviate `function` as `f`:

```
foo :: a -> ((b -> a) -> c) -> c
foo a f = f (\_ -> a)
```

#### Question 2

```
foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
```

OK, this time we need to make a `b`. We're given a `c` and a couple of functions for turning `a`s into `b`s and `c`s into `a`s:

```
foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
foo2 
   make_b_from_a 
   make_a_from_c 
   c 
      = b
```

Well, the only thing that can give us a `b` is `make_b_from_a`:

```
foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
foo2 
   make_b_from_a 
   make_a_from_c 
   c 
      = make_b_from_a a
```

but now we need an `a`, but we can use `make_a_from_c` for that, and we already have a `c`:

```
foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
foo2 
   make_b_from_a 
   make_a_from_c 
   c 
      = make_b_from_a (make_a_from_c c)
```

Let's shorten the names. I'm going to call the `(c->a)` one `f` because we use it before the other one, which I'll call `g`:

```
foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
foo2 g f c = g (f c)
```

We can take the last argument using a lambda:

```
foo2 :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
foo2 g f = \c -> g (f c)
```